# Specifying which object to get the super of

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, super

Like the titles says, I want to specify the super of an `NSArrayController`, something along the lines of `self = [super[NSArrayController] function]`, but have had no luck searching for this. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Edited** to remove abstract examples as they're confusing people as to the nature of my question.

The purpose of this is to programmatically do what a simple binding of 'add' from an NSArrayController to an NSButton would do in IB. There are several arrayControllers in my application so I want to be able to specify which one I want to obtain the super of by code.

The reason I am looking for the super of an NSArrayController is because I am under the impression that one should address the model rather than the controller (NSArrayController) and my model is a Core Data model that I believe I could get to by using the super of an NSArrayController I specify by name. Perhaps there is a more direct way of adding to the data model.

Comment: note that you should expect that every object initializes its super (and you must always write your initializers like this). this way, you never need to worry about initialization through the class hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry Justin, the init example I gave is diverting the point of my question and I've amended it to change that. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking a wrong question.

First, let's distinguish a **class** and an **instance** of the class. Note that there can be, and indeed often are, multiple instances of the same class.

A class `C` can be a **subclass** of another class `A`. Then `A` is the **superclass** of `C`. Suppose you have an instance `c` of the class `C`. Then, in the implementation of the methods of the class `C`, `self` stands for the instance of `c` itself, and `super` stands for the instance of `c` **as an instance of** its superclass `A`.  In a sense, an instance of the class `C` **is also** an instance of the class `A`.

Objects can have other relationships than being super or subclasses. For example, a class `C` can have in its interface an instance variable `B* b;` In this case, an instance `c` of the class `C` **has** a pointer to an instance  `b` of the class `B`. In this case, `c` is **not** an  instance of the class `B`.

The relationship between `NSArrayController` and the managed object context is one of the latter. An instance of `NSArrayController` contains a pointer to an instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` (moc).

So what you want to do is not to get the `super` of your `NSArrayController`. Instead, you want to get the moc associated to the `NSArrayController`. Now, how do you get it? To find it out, you open the reference in XCode or on the web at the Apple Developer Connection, [see here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Do that right now. Go through the methods. You don't find one giving you the moc.

Then, you go to the top of that page, and follow the superclass of `NSArrayController`. See [this reference of `NSObjectController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSObjectController_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSObjectController). Now, go through the list of the methods. You find `-[NSObjectController managedObjectContext]`, which does the job!

In conclusion: if you want the moc associated to the `NSArrayController`, you just need to do

```
NSManagedObjectContext* moc= [arrayController managedObjectContext];
```

where `arrayController` is the instance of the `NSArrayController` you want to deal with. e.g. If you have multiple instances of `NSArrayController`s in the nib, you should have multiple `IBOutlet`s in the app delegate, say, `arrayController1`, `arrayController2`, etc. (which are very bad variable names).  Then you choose the one you want to deal with.

Comment: Thankyou very Yuki for the time you (clearly) put into answering this. I'm obviously new to this so answers with this type of clarity are hugely helpful. I'm not 100% on your explanation yet but I'm getting there with a few re-reads.

Strangely, I've gotten the result I want by adding an object to arrayController itself as adding it to the managedObjectContext was giving me a warning that it may not work (and it didn't). I imagine this is from my unfamiliarity with what I'm doing so I'll continue reading on the subject. Many thanks again.