# Programmatically adding to a Core Data entity (like IB binding 'add')

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsarraycontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a core data model with an entity called **clients** that is made up of the following attributes:

[image: client model entity]

If I click on an '**add client**' button and bring up the following window:

[image: client window]

what would be the correct method to programmatically add a new entry for each property simultaneously (in a similar fashion to how a bound IB 'add' button would work with an `NSArrayController`) and have them appear in the textfields of the '**add client**' window to edit? The textfields in the '**add client**' window are bound to the corresponding properties (with one or two still missing) of the **client** entity. The code I have at the moment is:

```
- (IBAction)addNewClient:(id)sender;
{
    [addClientsWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    //NSManagedObjectContext *clientsMoc= [clientsController managedObjectContext];
    //[clientsMoc addObject:[clientsMoc newObject]];
    [clientsController addObject:[clientsController newObject]];
}
```

Which worked for other entities in this project but isn't working for **client** since I added relationship types (it throws up KVC errors in the console). I imagine it's because I am addressing the `NSArrayController` rather than the `NSManagedObjectContext` but the commented out code isn't working for me. This attempt follows on from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050732/specifying-which-object-to-get-the-super-of) as the question has changed a lot and I'm struggling to implement the advice given. I really need a good starting point and the apple dev docs aren't helping me make sense of this.

Thanks in advance!

**---- Update ----**

Am I explaining things badly in this question? I'm new here but thought there might be an attempt at an answer. Googling this was hard for some reason. I may have found something similar to a solution through an unrelated Google search. Luckily it was relevant to this.

```
- (IBAction)addNewClient:(id)sender;
{
    [addClientsWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    NSManagedObjectContext *clientsMoc= [clientsController managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *clientsEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                     insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Clients" 
                                       inManagedObjectContext:clientsMoc];
    [clientsEntity setValue:@"name" forKey:@"clientName"];
    [clientsEntity setValue:@"company" forKey:@"clientCompany"];
    [clientsEntity setValue:@"address" forKey:@"clientAddress"];
    [clientsEntity setValue:@"11111111" forKey:@"clientLandline"];
    [clientsEntity setValue:@"email@gmail.com" forKey:@"clientEmail"];
}
```

This created a full new entry for the clients entity - I didn't realise I would have to do an individual value for each property. The KVC errors continued though and I couldn't find a solution at all. Apple dev docs were actually helpful on this one, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/Troubleshooting.html), and adding `NSBindingDebugLogLevel 1` to the “Arguments to be passed at launch” list gave me details of exactly what was causing the problem. It was an old binding to an `NSTableColumn` that hadn't been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be the solution I was after:

```
- (IBAction)addNewClient:(id)sender;
{
    [addClientsWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    NSManagedObjectContext *clientsMoc= [clientsController managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *clientsEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                     insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Clients" 
                                       inManagedObjectContext:clientsMoc];
    [clientsEntity setValue:@"name" forKey:@"clientName"];
    [clientsEntity setValue:@"company" forKey:@"clientCompany"];
    [clientsEntity setValue:@"address" forKey:@"clientAddress"];
    [clientsEntity setValue:@"11111111" forKey:@"clientLandline"];
    [clientsEntity setValue:@"email@gmail.com" forKey:@"clientEmail"];
}
```

This created a full new entry for the clients entity - I didn't realise I would have to do an individual value for each property. The KVC errors continued though and I couldn't find a solution at all. Apple dev docs were actually helpful on this one, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/Troubleshooting.html), and adding `NSBindingDebugLogLevel 1` to the “Arguments to be passed at launch” list gave me details of exactly what was causing the problem. It was an old binding to an `NSTableColumn` that hadn't been updated.